# Number of n-tuples of 0's and 1's such that the sum of the entries is less than a fixed N<n

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Context: I was trying to find the expected value of a random variable with hypergeometric distribution $(N, M, n)$ by using the linearity of the expected value. On doing so, I found myself asking myself the question on the title because I wanted to define my $\Omega$ to be $\{\omega \in \{0,1\}^n: \sum \omega_i \leq N\}$. I then asked myself what was the size of $\Omega$ and narrowed it down to the following sum

$$\sum_{j=0}^{N} {n \choose j}$$

However, this does not really solve my problem because this sum seems rather complicated to manipulate. My question is then: Is there another approach to this? or how can I get a compact expression for that sum?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless $N$ is known to be very close to $1$, to $n$ or to $\frac n2$, there is no simpler way to write that sum.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can read about this in more detail?

Comment: @ManuelPico For instance, [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n) discusses the subject.